# Should questions about non-working code be asked in Stack Overflow or Code Review?

Tags: discussion

I have been working on some programs. I got it working after using global variables which I didn't want to use from the start. My **actual** program with local variables **isn't working**.

Can I ask such questions on Stack Overflow, or do they belong strictly to Code Review?

Comment: If it isn't working; normally stack overflow. But your problem seems a little too localized for SO.

Comment: It's not working. I was trying to implement singly linked list by using local variables only. I wasn't able to. I used global variables and the same code worked. So I guess I got some problem with my pointers. I guess SO...

Comment: It sounds like your returning/using the pointer of a local variable. Which can lead to undefined behavior (ie when the function returns). (Although I might be in the wrong language...) If you can create a small complete (compilable) example that demonstrates the problem. I would say post it on stackoverflow.

Comment: Actually I am returning pointer to a dynamically allocated memory location. I have a code that compiles. I'll post the question on SO.

Comment: @FDinoff This is the link for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258476/passing-pointers-between-functions-in-an-implementation-of-linked-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire point of Stack Overflow is to solve coding problems, so yes, you can and should ask them here, as long as you provide enough details for us to go on. For example, you need to tell us exactly **what** doesn't work.

Code Review is strictly for reviewing code that *does* work, but the author feels could be improved.

Comment: Link for my SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258476/passing-pointers-between-functions-in-an-implementation-of-linked-list